# Slack Slash Commands trigger GET request with no query parms

Tags: heroku, slack

I am trying to extend Slack by creating a Slack App that installs Slash Commands when the Slack App is installed by the user. The Slash Commands when triggered by a Slack chat user, will interact with an external web service that I am trying to develop.

According to the Slack documents for Slash Commands (https://api.slack.com/slash-commands), any Slash command will trigger a POST to the external service with a set of parameters in the POST body to indicate among other things, the user, the Slack channel, etc., that triggered the request.

When I made the web service I am developing on localhost available to the Internet using localtunnel (https://www.npmjs.com/package/localtunnel),  localtunnel actually creates a virtual server with some random hostname on `localtunnel.me`, e.g., https://wkbtfodclm.localtunnel.me, which connects to my localhost.

If I key in the Slash Command on my Slack chat, Slack successfully sends a POST request to the `localtunnel.me` server, which gets piped to my localhost.

However, after I deploy to Heroku, which has a domain, e.g., https://example.com, I notice that the Slash Command sends a GET request with no parameters to the server on Heroku. Has anybody experience this before?

Comment: Is it possible it's the ssl check? See https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#ssl. There *should* be a parameter `ssl_check=1`, but based on the documentation, I would expect that to be a query parameter (part of the URL). Does that match what you're seeing? (It might help to see the full HTTP request, including the full URL and headers.)

Comment: Thanks. Currently when I use the Slash command on Slack, it will contact the Slack server (as expected) but instead of contacting the external web service using POST, Slack contacts it using GET, but with no parameters, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything on the Slack side was working as expected. When I use the Slash command, Slack contacts its server, which then does a POST to the external web service https://example.com (as I configured) with all the parameters. However, the web service (due to DNS settings) will redirect https://example.com requests to https://**www**.example.com (NOTE the **www**). This resulted in the POST by Slack to be redirected as a GET with no URL queries. Configuring the Slash command to use https://www.example.com fixed this.